# The limit of a sequence of progressive integrals

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Define for each integer $k\ge 3$
$$B_k=\int_{x_1\le r}\int_{x_2\le\sqrt 2r}\cdots\int_{x_k\le\sqrt k r}\Phi(\sqrt{k+1}r-x_k)\left[\prod_{n=2}^k\phi(x_n-x_{n-1})\right]\phi(x_1)\,\mathrm dx_k\mathrm dx_{k-1}\cdots\mathrm dx_1,$$
where $r>0$ is some fixed real number, $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ are, respectively, the standard normal cdf and pdf.

It is clear that the sequence $\{B_k\}_{k\ge 3}$ is positive and decreasing since $\Phi(\sqrt{k+1}r-x_k)<1$ and
$$B_{k-1}=\int_{x_1\le r}\int_{x_2\le\sqrt 2r}\cdots\int_{x_k\le\sqrt k r}\left[\prod_{n=2}^k\phi(x_n-x_{n-1})\right]\phi(x_1)\,\mathrm dx_k\mathrm dx_{k-1}\cdots\mathrm dx_1,$$
and so it must converge.

I am interested in the exact value of the limit of this sequence, and in particular, if the limit is $0$. The difficulty is that $\Phi(\sqrt{k+1}r-x_k)$ is not bounded from above by a number strictly less than $1$ since it converges to $1$ as $x_k\to -\infty$, and so it seems hopeless to show that the sequence will be "asymptotically" geometric.

Can anyone give me some suggestions/hints on this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Could I ask where you encountered this kind of integral?  And should the ${x_k} \le \sqrt{k} r$ in the limits of integration be $|x_k| \le \sqrt{k} r$

Comment: @user6247850 This is related to the problem I posted before https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579662/a-lower-bound-on-the-probability-of-an-event. The limits of integration are what they are (i.e., $x_k\in (-\infty, \sqrt k r]$.